# why does "one-shot derivative" boundary condition hold for perpetual American call options?

Tags: options

When reading John Hull's book about perpetual options (Section 26.2: "perpetual American call and put options", 10th edition), I am a bit confused about the boundary conditions used here.

The author starts with discussion of the "one-shot derivative", which pays off a fixed amount $Q$ when stock price $S=H$ for the first time.  Then author claims the boundary conditions for this derivative are $f=Q$ when $S=H$ and $f=0$ when $S=0$.  I understand that $f=Q$ when $S=H$, but does anyone know why $f=0$ when $S=0$ (I expect that although $S=0$ at some time, it could still rise to $H$ at a future time therefore its price should not be exactly 0)?

Another question is, why does this discussion of the "one-shot derivative" apply to perpetual options?  In theory, we could wait forever with a perpetual option, so I assume it should not have this sort of "one-shot" behavior.

Comment: (1) When S=0 you hit an absorbing barrier and the price will remain at 0 (2) The *first time* you hit the optimal exercise boundary you should exercise the perpetual American option. In this sense the exercise is similar to the "one-shot" derivative you mention. The exercise will occur once and only once, the first time it is appropriate. Then the American option will no longer exist.

Comment: @noob2 Thanks for your comment!  Does the “absorbing barrier” mean that the stock is no longer available on the market?

Comment: Yes, that is an assumption in these models (the GBM models of stock price).

Comment: @noob2 Thanks!  This is really helpful!